# error: package com.some.provided.sdk.DownloadManager does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I have an import that resolves correctly in Android Studio but not in terminal (when building with Gradle).

I'm using the import as:

```
import com.some.provided.sdk.DownloadManager;
```

in a certain class A inside library libA.

And libA's config file contains an import for libB:

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile project('libB')
}
```

**Config**

```
dependencies = {
    1.23 = {
        libB = 1.1;
    };
};
```

While in LibB, I have the package as provided:

**build.gradle**

```
provided project('providedSdk')
```

**Config**

```
test-dependencies = {
    1.1 = {
        providedSdk = 1.0;
    };
};
```

The declaration under test-dependency and using as "provided" is as per the guidelines for the SDK. And this package has to be declared inside libB. libB is consumed by libA, however, libA cannot find the providedSdk.

Inside Android Studio, it works perfectly (the import works, when I "Go To Declaration" with it, it goes to the correct class in providedSdk), but when I build my APK in my terminal under gradle, it somehow cannot resolve that import.

Is there something I'm missing that I need to add for gradle to work that Android Studio automatically does?